# ¿Cómo devolver un JSON de una promesa?

Tags: angular, typescript, archivo, angular-material

He querido hacer esta consulta ya que llevo dos días queriendo hacer que funcione una Promesa en angular que me devuelva un `JSON`. Les comento que es la continuación de una pregunta anterior que hice y pude resolverla. Aún así he retomado lo que estaba haciendo y he estado pensando y dandole vueltas al asunto.

El resumen es que estoy haciendo un módulo de reportes, la idea es que al generar reportes automáticamente por `crontab` con un script `Python`, me esta generando cada cierta hora un reporte diario a unos datos, lo que ya hice es usar `typescript` y usar la librería `directory-tree` para que me devuelve esos directorios con esos archivos en forma de árbol.

Lo que ya hice es el front-end con `angular material` y usar el `mat-tree` que me genera la forma como los quiero visualizar en pantalla: aquí les dejo el [código](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directory-structure-download) y si pueden ver en la carpeta resources esta un ejemplo de la `data.ts` que me devuelve el `directory-tree` que mencione anteriormente.

El problema viene cuando trato de hacer el servicio y el controlador para que me obtenga la respuesta de las rutas, aquí agrego los modelos:

**fileNode.ts**

```
export interface FileNode {
  path?: string,
  name?: string,
  size?: number,
  children?: FileNode[],
  type?: string,
}
```

**treeNode,js**

```
export interface TreeNode {
  path?: string,
  name?: string,
  size?: number,
  extension?: string,
  type?: string,
  expandable: boolean;
  level: number;
}
```

Muestro la función del servicio, **report.service.ts**:

```
public async getListReport(): Promise<FileNode> {
    let API_URI = localStorage.getItem('API_URL');
    let URL=`${API_URI}/system`;
    return await this.http.get<FileNode>(`${URL}/reports/`).toPromise();
  }
```

Y la función dentro del **report.component.ts**:

```
async getAllReports() {
    let fileNode = await this.ReportService.getListReport();
    let data = JSON.stringify(fileNode);
    return data;  
}
```

El punto es cuando lo paso a `this.dataSource.data = this.getAllReports();`

Me lanza este error:

> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type
>   'FileNode[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Y al debuguear me percato que me esta devolviendo esto `Object { __zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: [] }` y dentro de eso me genera un `JSON`. Lo que intenté después es que  procedo en sacar todas las linea de la conversión y hacer un `console.log` y dentro me trae efectivamente todo el arbol con sus hijos, pero no limpio. De nuevo me parece lo del `__zone_symbol__value` y dentro esto:

```
children: Array [ {…} ]
​​
name: "REPORTES"
​​
path: "/var/reportes"
​​
size: 8919
​​
type: "directory"

.
.
.
```

Intenté hacer muchas otras cosas, como agregarle el `then` y retornar el resultado pero al parecer algo no me estoy percatando. Esperaré sus comentarios.

Comment: Quita el await después del return

Comment: Lo siento, pero eso no me ha servido sigue devolviéndome `Object { __zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: [] }`, lo que necesito que solo me devuelva un JSON como el `data.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar `await` en la llamada a la función `this.getAllReports();`

```
this.dataSource.data = await this.getAllReports();
```

Comment: No creo que el constructor me permita usar `async`, pero lo probaré en el `ngOnInit`. De todas formas gracias por responder.

Comment: O si no coloca el código que tienes en el constructor dentro de otra función. Y la llamas en el constructor eso funciona.

Comment: No fue necesario, pero si tuve que cambiar algunas cosas.